# find TH1 in AT89s52 micro controller in serial communication

Tags: c, 8051, baudrate

I want to establish serial communication between an 8-bit microcontroller, AT89S52, and a PC. I am using a crystal oscillator of 8 MHz frequency. For baud rate calculation I have used the following formula:

```
 Fbaud = (2^SMOD * Fosc)/(12*32*(256-TH1))
```

In my case

```
 SMOD = 1;
 Fbaud  =9600; // baud rate
 Fosc = 8MHz   // oscillator frequency
```

So using formula `TH1 = 251.659722222`

I have used `TH1  = 251` i.e. `0xFB` and also `252` i.e. `0xFC`. In both cases I am getting garbage values on Hyper terminal.

I have used following code::

```
#include <REGX52.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void serial_ini();
void serial_ini()
{ 
    SCON = 0x50; // mode 1 , 8 bit UART, enanle receiver
    TMOD = 0x20; // timer 1 mode 2(auto reload mode)
    TH1 = 0xFB ; // baud rate 9600 // crystal = 8.000 mhz..
    TR1 = 1; // Timer1 run
    TI = 1; 
}

void main()
{   
    serial_ini();
        while(1)
        {
            SBUF = 0x41;
            while(TI==0);
            TI=0;
        }
}
```

Please suggest to me how to calculate `TH1` for AT89S52 microcontroller.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 8952 but looking at some of my old 8752 code, I see that I have set the MSB of PCON with the comment `/* Use timer 1 for baud rate. */` (which may or may not be relevant to your device).

Comment: @MikeJ-UK I typically find that the number after the "8" indicates memory architecture with the core (i.e. 51/52) being common. 8052 = ROM-less, 8752 = OTP/EPROM, 8952 = Flash. The 89 series also tend to be exclusively Atmel though I've seen one or two that were not. So your comment does apply to the chip in question. But it may or may not apply depending on the OP's desired mode of operation.

Comment: Check out book by Mazidi on 8051! It has everything!

Answer (score 1):

All of the following information is available in [Atmel 8051 Microcontrollers Hardware Manual](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4316.pdf) which is referenced in Section 9 of the [AT89S52 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1919.pdf) as the place to look for information on Timers 0 and 1.

*Note: I'm assuming what you have in the comments is what you are trying to do.*

First off, your formula is wrong. If you're trying to use Mode 1, `SMOD` doesn't enter into it. Even so, `SMOD` is in `PCON` which you are not setting (which MikeJ-UK mentioned).

> The baud rate in Mode 0 is fixed:
>
> The baud rate in Mode 2 depends on the value of bit SMOD in Special
>   Function Register PCON.
>
> If SMOD = 0 (which is its value on reset), the baud rate is 1/64 the
>   oscillator frequency. If SMOD = 1, the baud rate is 1/32 the
>   oscillator frequency.
>
> **In the 80C51, the baud rates in Modes 1 and 3 are determined by the Timer 1 overflow rate. In case of Timer2, these baud rates can be
>   determined by Timer 1, or by Timer 2, or by both (one for transmit and
>   the other for receive).**

*Emphasis mine.*

Next, your `SCON` does not match the comment:

[image: SCON Register]

You have:

`SCON = 0x50`

Which equates to:

```
 FE SM0 SM1 SM2 REN TB8 RB8 TI  RI
 0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

So you're in Mode 2, 9-bit UART with the baud rate given as:

F<sub>CPU PERIPH</sub> /32 or /16

And serial reception disabled.

And then you've got:

`TI = 1`

Which you shouldn't do. You *clear* the interrupt flag. It's *set* by hardware.

Figure out exactly what you want to achieve and have a good look through those manuals. You'll probably need to rework your formula, change `SCON` and then set `TH1` and `TL1`.